# Static IP using Bash vs Router Interface

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, static-ip

What is the "proper" way to assign my CentOS 7 Virtual Machine a static IP? I assigned my Host system (Windows 8) a static IP through the router's administration interface, but every tutorial online shows steps for using Bash and `ifconfig`.

I am wondering specifically because I am having a hard assigning the CentOS VM a static IP as I don't see its MAC address in the router's admin console. It is on the same subnet, 192.168.1.x, however I suspect the MAC address is messed up somehow. I think my VM is using a different MAC address than what the Host expects. Could this be the problem?

EDIT:

I should add that I am using VMWare Workstation 12 and the Virtual Machine is running on a bridged connection (it has its own IP).

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine which IP adapter you are using and what its MAC is:

   ```
   [root@kcalmanc7 network-scripts]# ip address show
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 ::1/128 scope host
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
       link/ether 00:50:56:a6:5c:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 10.148.44.26/24 brd 10.148.44.255 scope global ens160
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea6:5c2b/64 scope link
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
       link/ether 52:54:00:6a:3c:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 500
       link/ether 52:54:00:6a:3c:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   ```

   (the second interface named 'ens160' shown above is the real network connection, MAC: 00:50:56:a6:5c:2b)
2. Ensure the MAC address of the interface you think you are using matches the MAC stated in the VM configuration:
   [image: Verify VM's MAC: 00:50:56:a6:5c:2b]
3. Edit the corresponding interface definition file

   ```
   [root@kcalmanc7 network-scripts]# pwd
   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
   [root@kcalmanc7 network-scripts]# ls -alp | grep ens160
   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   359 Aug  7  2015 ifcfg-ens160
   [root@kcalmanc7 network-scripts]# cat  ifcfg-ens160
   TYPE="Ethernet"
   BOOTPROTO=none
   DEFROUTE="yes"
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="yes"
   IPV6INIT="no"
   IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
   IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
   IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
   IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
   NAME="ens160"
   UUID="52744fd5-752a-4994-a7a7-1c4a8e0c3b13"
   ONBOOT="yes"
   HWADDR=00:50:56:A6:5C:2B
   IPADDR0=10.148.44.26
   PREFIX0=24
   GATEWAY0=10.148.44.254
   DNS1=10.148.44.11
   ```